# Text Adventure Room Movement

Tags: python, text, adventure

So I've been working to solve this code issue for a while, and I can't seem to get it. Whenever you try to move in any direction it will still print that you are stuck in the kitchen. I added a print current room line, and that shows that the program is moving it to other rooms, but isn't printing the correct description.

Any help would be lovely!

Thanks ahead of time.

```
class Room():
        room = []
        def __init__ ( self, desc, north , east , west , south, northwest, southwest, northeast, southeast):
            self.room.append(desc)
            self.room.append(north)
            self.room.append(east)
            self.room.append(west)
            self.room.append(south)
            self.room.append(northwest)
            self.room.append(southwest)
            self.room.append(northeast)
            self.room.append(southeast)
        def get_Desc(self):
            return self.room[0]
        def get_North(self):
            return self.room[1]
        def get_East(self):
            return self.room[2]
        def get_West(self):
            return self.room[3]
        def get_South(self):
            return self.room[4]
        def get_Northwest(self):
            return self.room[5]
        def get_Southwest(self):
            return self.room[6]
        def get_Northeast(self):
            return self.room[7]
        def get_Southeast(self):
            return self.room[8]



#Object Class
class Object():
    name = ""
    description = ""
    room = None
    def __init__ (self, newname, desc, newroom):
        self.name = newname
        self.description = desc
        self.room = newroom
    def get_Name():
        return name
    def set_Name(self , name):
        self.name = name
    def get_Desc(self):
        return description
    def set_Desc(self , description):
        self.description = description
    def get_Room(self):
        return self.description
    def set_Room(self, room):
        self.room = room




#This is a list of Objects in game
p_items = []
puppy = Object("Puppy", "OMG ROFL, LMAO, ITS CUTE AS ALL BALLS, GRAB IT AND SQUEEZE IT!!!", 2)
p_items.append(puppy)
Inventory = []
#This is a list of Rooms
room_list = []
room_1 = Room("This is the kitchen - 1. There is a passage to the North, East, and North East.", 3, 2, None, None , None, None, 7, None)
room_list.append (room_1)
room_2 = Room("This is the dining room - 2. There is a passage to the North, North East, and North West", 7, None, 1, None, 3, None, 6, None)
room_list.append(room_2)
room_3 = Room("This is the West hallway -3. There is a passage to the North, East, West, North East, North West, South East, and South West.", 4, 7, 1, None, 4, 1, 5, 2)
room_list.append(room_3)
room_4 = Room("This is the bedroom - 4. There is a passage to the East, West, and Southeast.", None, 5, 3, None, None, None, None, 7)
room_list.append(room_4)
room_5 = Room("This is the office -5. There is a passage to the South, West, Southwest, Northwest, and Northeast .", None, None, 7, 4 , 3, None, None, 6)
room_list.append(room_5)
room_6 = Room("This is the balcony. There is a passage to the West, North West, and South West.", None, None, None, 7, 5, 2, None, None )
room_list.append(room_6)
room_7 = Room("This is the East hallway. There is a passage to the North, South, and West, North East, North West, South East, and South West.", 5, None, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2)
room_list.append(room_7)

current_room = 3
done = False
while not done:
    print (current_room)
    print ((room_list[current_room]).get_Desc()) 
    for object in p_items:
        if object.get_Room() == current_room:
            print("There is an Object in this room : " + object.get_Name() + " - " + object.get_Desc())
    answer = input("Which direction would you like to go? \n N, E, S, W, NE, SE, NW, SW, O to open Inventory, P to pick up an item, or Q to quit ").lower()
    if answer == ("q"):
        done = True
    elif answer == ("n") and room_list[current_room].get_North() != None:
        current_room = room_list [current_room].get_North() 
    elif answer == ("e") and room_list[current_room].get_East() != None:
        current_room = room_list[current_room].get_East() 
    elif answer == ("w") and room_list[current_room].get_West() !=None:
        current_room = room_list[current_room].get_West() 
    elif answer == ("s") and room_list[current_room].get_South() !=None:
        curent_room = room_list[current_room].get_South() 
    elif answer == ("nw") and room_list[current_room].get_Northwest() !=None:
        current_room = room_list[current_room].get_Northwest() 
    elif answer == ("sw") and room_list[current_room].get_Southwest() !=None:
        curent_room = room_list[current_room].get_Southwest() 
    elif answer == ("ne") and room_list[current_room].get_Northeast() !=None:
        current_room = room_list[current_room].get_Northeast() 
    elif answer == ("se") and room_list[current_room].get_Southeast() !=None:
        curent_room = room_list[current_room].get_Souteasth() 
    elif answer == ("o"):
        print ("\nYou have the following objects in your Inventory:")
        for object in inventory:
            print ( "-" + object.get_Name() + " ; " + object.get_Desc());
    elif answer == ("p"):
        print ("\nThere are these items in this room:")
        for object in inventory:
            if object.get_Room() == current_room:
                print ( "-" + object.get_Name() + " ; " + object.get_Desc());                
                pu = input("Would you like to pick it up? (y/n): ").lower()
                if  pu == "y":
                    object.set_Room(666)
                    inventory.append(object)
                elif pu == "n":
                    print ( "Dont be dumb, pick it up!")
                else:
                    print ("That is not a valid option")  

                    print ("That is not a valid option")

    else:
        print ("\nThat is not a valid option!\n") 
    print (answer)
    print (current_room)


 #No quiting allowed everrrrr
```

Comment: There's far too much code here. Please cut it down to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The issue is I don't know which part of the code is making it not work.

Answer (score 3):

What causes your problem is your *Room* class.

```
class Room:
    room = []
```

This line makes room a class-level list (a static variable). So whenever you create a new instance of a Room, you append data to this class-level list, but the first indices, which are accessed by your game logic

```
def get_Desc(self):
    return self.room[0]

etc...
```

will always be the values of the same room.

When created inside a method, the list is no longer on class-level and your problem is fixed.

```
class Room():
    def __init__(self, desc, north, east, west, south, northwest, southwest, northeast, southeast):
        self.room = []
```